# is it better to read from LIST or from Database?

Tags: python, database, kivy

I work on a raspberry pi project and use Python + Kivy for such reasons:

I read some string values comming from a device installed in a field every 300ms.

As soon as I see certain value I trigger a python thread to run another function which takes the string and stores it in a list and timestamp it.

My kivy app displays the value stored in the list and run some other functions.

The question is: Is it better approach to save received strings into DB and let kivy read DB or is it better for Python to append list and let to run another function that runs through list and trigger kivy task?

Comment: It is almost def better to subclass list and add a listener so you don't have to busywait.

Comment: @Natecat well if this app runs for days, the list will be huge. Wouldnt that use up all the ram?

Comment: i append list and pop(0) if lenght of list is > 50 so i loose historical data... would DB response quickly to web so web updates displayes value in e.g.  <0.2s?

Comment: Do you need logging capibilities

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you corectly but i do not need to record capabilities.

Comment: Ok so the list never gets larger than 50. Then I would go with list

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches have pros and cons.

A database is designed to store and query data. You can query data easily (SQL) from multiple processes. If you don't have multiple processes and no complicated querys a database doesn't really offers that much. Maybe persistence if that is a concern for you. If you don't need the features a database offers, don't use one.

If you simply want to store a bit data a list is better. It's probably faster because you don't need inter process communication. Also if you store the data in the database you will still need to get it into the python process somehow, and then you will probably put it in a list.

Based on your requests a database doesn't offer any features you need, so you should go with a simple list.